# I've updated CentOS 7 and now nginx doesn't start automaticaly on system boot

Tags: nginx, centos7

I've updated my server's OS (CentOS 7) through the command "yum update" and now NGINX doesn't start during system boot.

At startup log shows:

```
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname nm-dispatcher: req:1 'hostname': start running ordered scripts...
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7261] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'dhclient'
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7261] manager: rfkill: WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7261] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7262] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7264] Loaded device plugin: NMBondDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7264] Loaded device plugin: NMBridgeDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7265] Loaded device plugin: NMDummyDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7265] Loaded device plugin: NMEthernetDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7265] Loaded device plugin: NMInfinibandDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7265] Loaded device plugin: NMIPTunnelDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7265] Loaded device plugin: NMMacsecDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7295] Loaded device plugin: NMMacvlanDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7295] Loaded device plugin: NMTunDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7295] Loaded device plugin: NMVethDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7295] Loaded device plugin: NMVlanDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7295] Loaded device plugin: NMVxlanDeviceFactory (internal)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7351] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib64/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7377] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib64/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7389] device (lo): link connected
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7396] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7413] manager: (dummy0): new Dummy device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7428] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7448] device (eth0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7474] device (eth0): link connected
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname kernel: 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth0
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7500] manager: (teql0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7550] manager: (tunl0): new IPTunnel device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7565] manager: (gre0): new IPTunnel device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7603] manager: (gretap0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7613] manager: (ip_vti0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7623] manager: (ip6_vti0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/9)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7638] manager: (sit0): new IPTunnel device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/10)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7648] manager: (ip6tnl0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/11)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7668] manager: (ip6gre0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/12)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7864] device (eth0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7883] policy: auto-activating connection 'System eth0'
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7914] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'System eth0' (5fb06bd0-0bb0-7ffb-45f1-d6edd65f3e03)
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7920] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7924] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464890.7942] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname firewalld[3266]: WARNING: ICMP type 'beyond-scope' is not supported by the kernel for ipv6.
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname firewalld[3266]: WARNING: beyond-scope: INVALID_ICMPTYPE: No supported ICMP type., ignoring for run-time.
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname firewalld[3266]: WARNING: ICMP type 'failed-policy' is not supported by the kernel for ipv6.
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname firewalld[3266]: WARNING: failed-policy: INVALID_ICMPTYPE: No supported ICMP type., ignoring for run-time.
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname firewalld[3266]: WARNING: ICMP type 'reject-route' is not supported by the kernel for ipv6.
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname firewalld[3266]: WARNING: reject-route: INVALID_ICMPTYPE: No supported ICMP type., ignoring for run-time.
Sep 15 05:41:30 server_hostname kernel: random: crng init done
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464891.0265] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464891.0313] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464891.0323] device (eth0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464891.0325] device (eth0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464891.0326] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464891.0480] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464891.0481] policy: set 'System eth0' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464891.0493] device (eth0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464891.0498] manager: startup complete
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464891.0502] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [eth0]: new request (3 scripts)
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [eth0]: start running ordered scripts...
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname nm-dispatcher: req:3 'connectivity-change': new request (3 scripts)
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Started Network Manager Wait Online.
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname nm-dispatcher: req:3 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname network: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname network: Bringing up interface eth0:  [  OK  ]
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Started LSB: Bring up/down networking.
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Reached target Network.
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting Network.
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Reached target Network is Online.
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting Network is Online.
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting LSB: Start and stop FastCGI processes...
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting MySQL Community Server...
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting Fail2Ban Service...
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting Dynamic System Tuning Daemon...
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting Pure-FTPd FTP server...
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting /etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility...
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname nginx: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [**My IPv6 address here**]:80 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname nginx: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: nginx.service failed.
    Sep 15 04:33:05 server_hostname systemd: Started /etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility.
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname spawn-fcgi: Starting spawn-fcgi: [  OK  ]
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname systemd: Started LSB: Start and stop FastCGI processes.
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname systemd: Started Dynamic System Tuning Daemon.
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname fail2ban-client: 2017-09-15 05:41:31,760 fail2ban.server         [3616]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.9.6
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname fail2ban-client: 2017-09-15 05:41:31,761 fail2ban.server         [3616]: INFO    Starting in daemon mode
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname mysqld_safe: 170915 05:41:31 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname mysqld_safe: 170915 05:41:31 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Sep 15 05:41:31 server_hostname systemd: Started Fail2Ban Service.
Sep 15 05:41:32 server_hostname systemd: Started MySQL Community Server.
Sep 15 05:41:32 server_hostname systemd: Started ISPConfig DC Sync.
Sep 15 05:41:32 server_hostname systemd: Starting ISPConfig DC Sync...
Sep 15 05:41:32 server_hostname NetworkManager[3277]: <info>  [1505464892.7411] policy: set 'System eth0' (eth0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Sep 15 05:41:33 server_hostname systemd: Started The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
Sep 15 05:41:33 server_hostname systemd: Reached target Multi-User System.
Sep 15 05:41:33 server_hostname systemd: Starting Multi-User System.
Sep 15 05:41:33 server_hostname systemd: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Sep 15 05:41:33 server_hostname systemd: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Sep 15 05:41:33 server_hostname systemd: Startup finished in 1.741s (kernel) + 3.868s (userspace) = 5.609s.
```

Curiously, I can start NGINX manually after booting, and it works fine.

CentOS 7.4.1708

NGINX 1.12.1

/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service

```
[Unit]
Description=nginx - high performance web server
Documentation=http://nginx.org/en/docs/
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Is something interesting in logs? Like some missing service dependency etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the Linode's Forum.

Create the file: /etc/sysctl.d/80-network.conf with the content:

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
```

...to allow daemons to bind to non-existing network interfaces.

Source: https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=15219

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is here:
bind() to [**My IPv6 address here**]:80 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)

when you start nginx manually,all other daemons are started. Nginx doesn't start while booiting because of this problem. All other errors appear in the log after this event.check nginx.com-maybe thereis something whith addresses (Cannot assign requested address error.) Nginx with clean config works fine (i mean autostart) after update of CentOS(v 7.4).

Comment: To build on this a little, confirm by removing the IP6 bind / configuration statement. If that fixes it you'll want to look into whether IP6 is working on the server, and if so if Nginx is correctly configured.

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: As I said before, I can start NGINX manually after booting, and it works fine.

Comment: when you start nginx manually,all other daemons are started. Nginx doesn't start while booiting because of this problem. All other errors appear in the log after this event.check nginx.com-maybe thereis something whith addresses (Cannot assign requested address error.)

Comment: I added more logs. Apparently something with the NetworkManager update.

Comment: It looks like a bug. More info here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1479951

Comment: You're right. I don't think we'll have a solution until the next update. Thank you!